# What's the difference between "suasive" and "persuasive"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

What's the difference in usage between *suasive* and *persuasive*?  I just read the former used, here on this StackExchange, where the latter would have worked perfectly, IMO.  Is there a subtle distinction between the two words?  Can anyone give me an example where using *suasive* would be compellingly better than using *persuasive*? And finally, as I'd never seen the word *suasive* before today, does that mean *suasive* is archaic, or just used in a particular context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Suasive** is an adjective that, in Linguistics (Grammar), *"denotes a class of English verbs, for example, **insist**, whose meaning includes the notion of persuading and that take a subordinate clause whose verb may either be in the subjunctive or take a modal."*
2. **Persuasive** is an adjective as well, that means being *"good at persuading someone to do or believe something through reasoning or the use of temptation: `an informative and persuasive speech.`" OR "`She was very persuasive!`"*

The difference, then, is that while the former denotes a grammatical class for **verbs**, the second is adopted the way you already know, with people, situations, etc.

**EDIT NOTE**: In the OED it says that a speech can be "suasive" but considering the OALD and my dictionary didn't have it, I supposed it was an old use or it fell into disuse. So I checked the [Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=suasive%20speech,%20persuasive%20speech&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) on google and it confirmed what Billare said and what I was thinking.

Comment: Although "suasive" and "suasion" are much less common, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suasive) does have recent uses of "suasion". It's unclear whether it's being used simply for variety (to avoid repeating persuasion/influence/etc) or if it has a slightly different meaning - from their examples it might be intended to mean something subtler, and less complete or total ("per-" is often used to indicate completion).